# Latest Xcode build only transfers onto iPad (device or simulator) after running twice

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Running Xcode 4.3 and running into the following issue:

When I make a code change and click 'Run' to deploy it onto either the iPad Simulator or a device I do not see the latest changes reflected on the device.  Clicking 'Run' again will cause it to be deployed again and then I see the changes.

Trying a clean before building does not help.  Deleting the app from the iPad/Simulator will work.

I believe this issue may be project based.  I made a simple side project to test and I did not see this issue.

This is a huge time sync when I build and deploy 30 times an hour :)

Comment: You can have have some weird setting in you build path, build configurations or scheme settings. Could you please post some screenshot of the different options? That's definitely a project issue.